# what Service connection should we add to "Invoke REST API: POST" in Azure pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

i'm creating a **Service Connection** to **Invoke REST API: POST task** in the azure pipeline as per the below document, but im not sure sure what service connection should be added and what should be the server URL.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/http-rest-api?view=azure-devops

Comment: Is there any update about this ticket? Feel free to let me know if the answer could give you some help. Just a remind of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) .

Answer (score 1):

We can use Azure Resource Manager or Generic service connections in invoke REST API task. The Azure Resource Manager service connection is used to invoke an Azure management API and the Generic service connection is used for all other APIs. You can find this in the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/http-rest-api?view=azure-devops).

Connection type:

[image: Connection type]
The server URL is base URL for the call. Here are my examples:

1. Generic

Server URL in the service connection: `https://dev.azure.com/{Organization name}/{Project name}`

Configuration of my task:

[image: Configuration]

This REST API is used to create a new work item: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1

The full URL is `https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/workitems/${type}?api-version=6.1-preview.3`. It is composed of the server URL in the service connection and the URL suffix in the task.

2. Azure Resource Manager

Configuration of my task:

[image: Configuration]

This REST API is used to get all permissions the caller has for a resource group: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/authorization/permissions/listforresourcegroup

The full URL is `https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourcegroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/permissions?api-version=2015-07-01`. You just need to add `subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourcegroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/permissions?api-version=2015-07-01` in the URL suffix.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response,

What is the URL to call an API exposed through APIM or just a logic app API?

I have similar requirement:
I need to create a logic app, publish it through APIM and call POST method from yaml pipeline.
I came across "Invoke REST API" task but not sure on the URI suffix I can use to call an API.

Regards,
Vivek