# NonAuthoritativeInformation error while invoking rest api through pre deployment gates

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

My release pipeline is invoking rest api from pre deployment gates

but I keep getting

```
    2022-04-20T16:44:28.3116572Z GET https://dev.azure.com/myOrg/myProj/_apis/test/runs?minLastUpdatedDate=2022-04-17&maxLastUpdatedDate=2022-04-17&api-version=6.0
                    Response Code: NonAuthoritativeInformation
                    Response: 
    
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
....
```

I have this in service connection

[image]

and the below as pre deployment gate

[image]

When the request is sent through postman, it works fine. I just mention PAT in authorization field in headers

What is my pre deployment gate configuration missing here?

Comment: The auth token has to be base 64 encoded. `System.AccessToken` is not base64 encoded.

Comment: @Daniel Mann Thanks . How do I do that? I tried to look around but could not get anything. I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63769002/what-service-connection-should-we-add-to-invoke-rest-api-post-in-azure-pipeli) and this is exactly what I am doing but I am receiving the error mentioned above. [This post](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/what-is-the-scope-of-the-token-in-systemaccesstoke/618929) marked solution suggests to use variables in url but provide no example. Any idea from these posts on solution ?Or any pointers on passing base64 token in header?